# Angular Firestore document update causing infinite loop in subscription

Tags: firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I understand the issue but can't figure out the workaround. I am querying a specific document to extract an array of token strings. I need to append a new token to the end of this string and then update the current document with this new token array.

To do this, I have subscribed to a query and within, I update that document. But of course, when you update the same object, the subscription runs again thus creating an infinite loop. I tried incorporating a `take(1)` pipe rxjs operator but that did not change anything. Any suggestions?

Here's my code:

```
this.afs.collection('users').doc(user.userUID).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((user: userModel) => {
    const currentTokens: string[] = user.notifTokens ? user.notifTokens : [];

    //token variable is provided outside this query
    currentTokens.push(token);

    //this next lines causes the subscription to trigger again
    userRef.doc(user.userUID).update({notifTokens: currentTokens})
  })
```

Comment: IMO, there must the surrounding/related code, because what's in that snippet won't - of itself - effect an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you avoid using a subscription in this situation, for exactly this reason. I realize the [Angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) don't list this method, but the base Firebase package [includes a .get() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)... and while the AF2 docs don't mention the `.get()` method... [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/firestore/document/document.ts) shows that it is supported.

Try something like:

```
this.afs.collection('users').doc(user.userUID).get().then( (user: userModel) => {
    if (user.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", user.data());

        // Do stuff with the info you get back here

        const currentTokens: string[] = user.data().notifTokens ? user.data().notifTokens : [];
        currentTokens.push(token);
        userRef.doc(user.data().userUID).update({notifTokens: currentTokens})

    } else {
        // user.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```